# Javascript function not working on validating the form

Tags: javascript

I have this form

```
<tr>
    <td><h5> Name</h5> <asp:TextBox ID="tb_name" ClientIDMode="Static"  CssClass="tb_orderByPhn" runat="server"  /> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><h5>Phone</h5> <asp:TextBox ID="tb_phone" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="tb_orderByPhn" runat="server" /> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><h5>Email</h5> <asp:TextBox ID="tb_email" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="tb_orderByPhn" runat="server" /> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td> <asp:LinkButton id="btn_order1"  class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success btn_rad " OnClick="btn_order" OnClientClick=" return validate_order();"   runat="server" >Order now <i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right  " ></i></asp:LinkButton></td>
</tr>
```

The form is validated by the javascript as

```
function validate_order() {

    if (document.getElementById("tb_phone").value == "") {
        document.getElementById("tb_phone").style.borderColor="red";
        return false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("tb_email").value == "") {
        document.getElementById("tb_email").style.borderColor="red";
        return false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("tb_name").value == "") {
        document.getElementById("tb_name").style.borderColor="red";
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

But when i click the button keeping the field empty i get red border on one textbox only(the first textbox in the javascript function ie tb_phone) instead of all three.Please can anyone explain this?

Comment: You also need to set `1px solid` on the other two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a snippet for you. It's faster to save the element in a variable if you use it more than one time. This code will also remove the border if the input is valid after a 2nd submit.

If you want to do it better, you can create a 'validateInput' function, and validate each input with the same function.

```js
function validateOrder() {
    var valid = true,
        name = document.getElementById("tb_name"),
        phone = document.getElementById("tb_phone"),
        email = document.getElementById("tb_email");
 
    validateInput.call(name);  
    validateInput.call(phone);
    validateInput.call(email);

  
    if (!validateInput.call(name) || !validateInput.call(phone) || !validateInput.call(email))
      valid = false;
  
    return valid;
}

function validateInput(){
  if(this.value == ""){
    this.style.border = "1px solid red";
    return false;  
  }
  else{
    this.style.border = "none";
    return true;  
  }
}
```

```html
<tr><td><h5> Name</h5> <input id="tb_name" onkeyup="validateInput.call(this);" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><h5>Phone</h5> <input id="tb_phone" onkeyup="validateInput.call(this);" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><h5>Email</h5> <input id="tb_email" onkeyup="validateInput.call(this);" /></td></tr>

<tr><td><button onclick="validateOrder();" >Order now</button></td></tr>
```

Comment: how do i remove the red border once the value is entered without clicking button..please help

Comment: @Chelsea, i updated the snippet! I hope you understand what is happening.

Comment: Wow! that was nice ,Thanks.If its not too much to ask Can you please suggest me some resources where I can learn other javascripts much needed in web.

Comment: Thanks! I have learn much at http://www.codecademy.com. First I started there with JavaScript, and after that jQuery (which i use most of the time). Also http://www.w3schools.com/js is a good resource to get started with js. Good luck in learning!

Answer (score 2):

It's because once you've made the first box red, you've done `return false;`. That terminates the function, bypassing all of the code below it.

If you want to do all three, use a variable, set it, and then return it at the end.

```
function validate_order() {
    var valid = true;

    if (document.getElementById("tb_phone").value == "") {
        document.getElementById("tb_phone").style.border = "1px solid red";
        valid = false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("tb_email").value == "") {
        document.getElementById("tb_email").style.borderColor = "Red";
        valid = false;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("tb_name").value == "") {
        document.getElementById("tb_name").style.borderColor = "Red";
        valid = false;
    }

    return valid;
}
```

---

Side note: I notice in the first block you're doing this:

```
document.getElementById("tb_phone").style.border = "1px solid red";
```

but in the next two blocks you're doing this:

```
document.getElementById("tb_email").style.borderColor = "Red";
document.getElementById("tb_name").style.borderColor = "Red";
```

I don't know the CSS applied to these elements, but I would expect those three to be consistent with each other. (Also, CSS color names are almost universally written in all lower case.)

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate_order() {

if (document.getElementById("tb_phone").value == "") {
    document.getElementById("tb_phone").style.borderColor="red";
    return false;
}

if (document.getElementById("tb_email").value == "") {
    document.getElementById("tb_email").style.borderColor="red";
    return false;
}

if (document.getElementById("tb_name").value == "") {
    document.getElementById("tb_name").style.borderColor="red";
    return false;
}
return true;
```

}

Try this , will work

Answer (score 0):

Your control are set as [runat="server"] so you have to use as follows

function validate_order() {

```
if (document.getElementById("<%=tb_phone.ClientID%>").value == "") {
    document.getElementById("%=tb_phone.ClientID%>").style.border = "1px solid red";
    return false;
}

if (document.getElementById("%=tb_email.ClientID%>").value == "") {
    document.getElementById("t%=b_email.ClientID%>").style.borderColor = "Red";
    return false;
}

if (document.getElementById("%=tb_name.ClientID%>").value == "") {
    document.getElementById("%=tb_name.ClientID%>").style.borderColor = "Red";
    return false;
}
return true;
```

}